# Is it safe to create an element called <window>?

Tags: html, dom

I am a big fan of creating new elements and naming them what they are. I'm making a website with windows, and you might already see the question.

**Can I safely make an element named `<window>`?**

In my code, I have an element named `<window>`. I'm wondering if it's safe to have that element since there's a significant DOM element also named `window`.

I'm also selecting it with jQuery with `$("window")`. This also seems unsafe, but is it?

Comment: Think about this. What is a browser to do with an unknown tag like that?

Comment: @Rob custom tags are absolutly valid

Comment: @SebastianSpeitel Yes they are. So how is he identifying it as such and what will a browser do with an unknown tag like that?

Comment: @MattF. - You probably want to provide a more complete example of what you're doing.

Comment: Why not just adding a "namespace" to your tag, such as '<matt-window />` just to be sure. If it's good for material design (in angularjs) it will be good for you. Isn't?

Comment: `window` isn't a DOM element. It's an object *containing* a DOM document.

Comment: @MoshFeu Cause this isn't XHTML

Comment: `window` is not a DOM *element*. It's a global variable, yes, but `$("window")` should work just fine and not behave like `$(window)`.

Comment: @Rob see T.J' answer..

Comment: @MoshFeu See my comments above. This is neither a custom tag as presented in the question nor XHTML.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, `window` is not a safe custom element tag — or at least, it's an invalid tag name for a custom element, which to my mind makes it "not safe." The [custom element](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/custom-elements.html#valid-custom-element-name) part of the specification is clear that the tag name of custom elements must contain a `-`. `window` does not. From a note in the spec:

> These requirements ensure a number of goals for valid custom element names:
>
> - ...
> - ...
> - **They contain a hyphen**, used for namespacing and to ensure forward compatibility (since no elements will be added to HTML, SVG, or MathML with hyphen-containing local names in the future).

*(my emphasis)*

It's entirely possible that at some stage, HTML could have a `window` tag added to it.

Comment: Considering the future is something I wouldn't have thought of. Thanks.